# mysql performance with select not in

Tags: mysql, performance

I want to find new markets that have been added to a plan table after date 2012-05-17.
This select works but performance is slow with 16k records.
When I remove the second distinct keyword, performance improves greatly and I get the same results, but I still need this select to be much faster.  It takes about 25 seconds.  There must be a faster way?

```
select distinct(market) 
from plan
where date_added > '2012-05-17'
and market not in (select distinct(market) from plan where date_added < '2012-05-17')
```

Comment: `distinct` is not a function. So writing `distinct(market)` does not make sense. And you really don't need the distinct anyway in the sub-select. But as far as I can tell you don't need the sub-select at all as you already only get markets added after the desired date.

Comment: I know it only hurts performance and was unnecessary, but I don't know how to improve performance further.... I changed the word 'function' to the correct word 'keyword'

Comment: One option I'd consider is doing a `max(date_added)` in a sub-select and then selecting only those records where `max(date_added) < '2012-05-17'`.  Just an idea.  Also, in Oracle, I've seen dramatic improvements using `MINUS`, but not sure if mysql has that.

Comment: Do you have more than one row with the same value in the market column, but with different dates?

Comment: yes.. and new markets can be added at any time.  My date field is actually a datetime field.  I want those new markets that have been added after a specific time that do not exist before that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not certain this will improve your performance, but it's another approach:

```
select market
  from (select market,
               min(date_added) min_date
          from plan
         group by market) as sub_plan
 where sub_plan.min_date > '2012-05-17';
```

Also, let me caveat that I'm an Oracle guy, so please forgive small syntactical differences.

Comment: this does not exclude markets that were added before 2012-05-17.

Comment: @panofish, It doesn't?  If the minimum date for a market in the sub-query is less than 2012-05-17, it will not be selected by the outer query.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm sorry.. I am not communicating my problem very well.  The market column is not a key and values can repeat.  If I do a select distint(market) before a date and a select distinct(market) after the same date... The 2 lists may be the same, but there may be a few new markets in the second list that do not exist in the first list.

Comment: Maybe I need normalize and create a table for market and other columns where I need to do this logic?

Comment: @panofish, My query handles the case you describe.  The inner query looks at ALL of the markets and finds the minimum date associated with every distinct market.  Then it down-selects to just those that have a minimum date greater than the literal date provided.  In other words, only those that are new since the literal date.  What part of that is failing?

Comment: give me a moment.. I will run it.

Comment: holy -bleep- , I'm an idiot... that ran in .109 seconds and gave me the results I wanted!  My above select worked, but took 25 seconds.  You are the winner and a genius!

Comment: btw... my date is actually a datetime field, which explains why there are so many records with the same market... and why your solution works so well.  THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just leave out this whole line?

```
and market not in (select distinct(market) from plan where date_added < '2012-05-17'
```

It's redundant since you already specify that date_added is > 2012-05-17.

Comment: Also, you have two restrictions: 1) date_added > 2012-05-17  2) NOT date_added < 2012-05-07.  This totally ignores the case where date_added = 2012-05-17.  Don't forget that you can use ">=" or "<=" where appropriate.

Comment: I think he's trying to capture only those records whose very first `date_added` occurs after 2012-05-17.  That would explain why he's also trying to eliminate records that have a date_added entry prior to that date.

Comment: nope.. the market values may repeat or their may be a new market value at any time.  I want the new markets that have been added after a date that do not exist before that same date... hence the >date and <date

Comment: Actually, my date is a datetime field so it includes time which I excluded to simplify the question